# Adding CSS to embed button on Carrd.co

Tags: html, css, button, embed

I am trying to add CSS to my embedded "Pay" button from **selly.gg** on my site created on **carrd.co**.

```
<button data-selly-product="c2f270b2">Pay</button>
```

I'm looking for some sort of link to a css file, but there are none anywhere. Please let me know how I can get this to work.

Comment: You can use the code inspector fo the browser to see what's the exact HTML code that the button `<button data-selly-product="c2f270b2">Pay</button>` add to your page, with that information you can write your own CSS for that button. Could you add the final HTML code of the button to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Following worked fine for me

```
button{
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  background-color: #FDB714;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```